# Having trouble iterating through object in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angular, typescript

I have an app in `Angular 10` I am writing. I am passing in a `JSON` string. I am trying to convert that to an object. I am getting a compiler error saying

> 'inputObj' is not iterable.

The code is this:

```
interface FileNode {
  name: string;
  data?: FileNode[];
}
....
....
ParseData(input: string){
    let output: FileNode[] = [];
    let children: FileNode[] = [];
    let inputObj: any[] = JSON.parse(input);
    
    for (let node of inputObj) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(node));
    }
    
    // this is what I need in the end...
    let newNode: FileNode = {
      name: 'Name',
      data: children,
    }

    output.push(newNode);
    return output;
  }
```

The data I am passing in is this:

```
{
  "Data":"/",
  "Nodes":[
    {
      "Data":"New Text Document.txt",
      "Nodes":[]
    },
    {
      "Data":"L2",
      "Nodes":[
        {
          "Data":"README.txt",
          "Nodes":[]
        },
        {
          "Data":"L2A",
          "Nodes":[
            {
              "Data":"README_L2A.txt",
              "Nodes":[]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Data":"L3",
      "Nodes":[
        {
          "Data":"README_L3.txt",
          "Nodes":[]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong. I am sure this is something stupid but I just cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you would like to loop through `Nodes` array you would need to get it first like

```
 let inputObj:any = JSON.parse(input);
 const nodes:any[] = inputObj['Nodes'];
```

then iterate.

also your structure seems deeply nested, you could make some recursive calls like

```
logNodes(node:any){
  if (!node || node.length === 0)
    return;
  console.log(node);
  for(n of node['Nodes'])
    this.logNodes(node.Nodes[i]);
}

ngOnInit(){
  let inputObj:any = JSON.parse(input);
  const nodes:any[] = inputObj['Nodes'];
  this.logNodes(nodes)
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: @JAKDev what is exactly the rror message you get, did you console log `input` variable what do you get?

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. I am not getting an error but I am not getting output. I think this is a separate issue with my code.

Comment: @JAKDev not understanding, this solved your issue? still what do you get as output when you do `console.log(input)`?

Comment: {"Data":"New Text Document.txt","Nodes":[]}
{"Data":"L2","Nodes":[{"Data":"README.txt","Nodes":[]},{"Data":"L2A","Nodes":[{"Data":"README_L2A.txt","Nodes":[]}]}]}
{"Data":"L3","Nodes":[{"Data":"README_L3.txt","Nodes":[]}]}

Comment: @JAKDev ok so everything is working fine now?